# Does "./" (dot slash)html, cause problems for any browsers

Tags: html, css

In the world of shells, `./` is fairly common and not considered to be a dangerous way to refer to the current directory when specifying a path.

In HTML, however, we almost always leave out the `./` and just put the name of the file we want. Is this a stylistic convention, or is it due to some browsers simply not understanding `./` to mean "Current Directory"?

Comment: I don't fully know, but i would imagine it's more of a case you don't need to use it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason to use this in the shell is that the shell looks up executable commands in a mix of its internal commands, PATH directories and the current working directory. By using `./command`, you unambiguously tell it to use `command` in the current directory, not elsewhere.

This does not apply to HTML/HTTP at all, so there's no good reason to use it. `path` and `./path` always mean exactly the same thing in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I used to use `./` a lot while starting out with HTML, as far as I've ever seen it be used none of my browsers ever had problems with it.

I personally stopped using it to keep my code cleaner, also if you use it you are more likely to accidentally forgetting the `.` which would mean you would be pointing at the document root which could lead to annoying little bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I use `./`. I think is a good way for keep my code consequent: if i use `../` for parent directory i should use `./` for current directory although its supposed that its implicit.

Anyway, i think i've never had problems with any browser using this.

Regards.